# Return inner observable with which operator?

Tags: typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

chat.service.ts:

```
  getUserChats(): Observable<Chat[]> {
    return this.auth.currUser
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        flatMap(user => this.afs
          .collection('chats', ref => {
            console.log(user.uid)
            return ref.where('members', 'array-contains', `/users/${user.uid}`);
          })
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(action => {
                const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                return {id, ...data};
              });
            })
          ) as Observable<Chat[]>)
      );
  }
```

Is there a way to return the inner Observable which holds the chats from the user?

```
this.afs
              .collection('chats', ref => {
                console.log(user.uid)
                return ref.where('members', 'array-contains', `/users/${user.uid}`);
              })
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(
                map(actions => {
                  return actions.map(action => {
                    const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                    const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                    return {id, ...data};
                  });
                })
              ) as Observable<Chat[]>
```

In the inner observable I need to wait for the user.uid to query for the chats.

Comment: What is the inner Observable?

Comment: @martin The firestore query: this.afs.collection('chats' .....

Comment: Just use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: Still doesn't work well @martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switchmap is okay, works well with it the problem was that 'array-contains' doesnt work for DocumentReferences in Firestore